# RSA Key - Exponent and Modulus? (Qt / Android / C++)

Tags: c++, qt, rsa

I'm working on an Android application in Qt and have a requirement to encrypt a given string using a public key which is to be received from a network request.

Making the request is okay but it returns Base64 encoded “Modulus” and “Exponent” parts of an RSA public key.

Here I'm a bit lost on how to proceed or what to even look for, searching around the closest I found was a [Python library](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA-module.html#construct) that constructs a key from its components. But I can't seem to find an equivalent for C++/Qt, only ways to generate new keys from a random number generator.

Could anyone point me in the right direction on how to 'combine' these parts into a key / use them to encrypt a string?

Any help would be greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to do the crypto code yourself? If not, have you looked at libcrypto? It's originally (I think) part of OpenSSL, but there are many implementations, and I am fairly sure it comes with Qt for Android too, as it is needed for Qt SSL network stuff.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look into libcrypto. And no I don't need to roll anything myself - just wondering if someone had done this already and knew of a good library or way on how to do it. It's not an area I'm too familiar with